# Gitignore a file if file with different extension exists

Tags: git, wildcard, gitignore, githooks

In a project where for instance a parser is involved, some source code is the product of a program. For instance `yacc` generates - based on a `.yy` file - a source code file that implements the parser.

Since small modifications in the `.yy` file can lead to large changes in the corresponding source code file after compilation and since  the resulting source code is (almost) never altered after it is generated. Such source code files are perfect candidates for the `.gitignore` list.

Now one can of course write such files manually to the list:

```
lexer1.cpp
parser1.cpp
lexer2.cpp
parser2.cpp
```

But it is likely when one builds a new parser, he/she will forget to add the file to the list.

Is there a way to *specify* a pattern that acts as follows:

> Given a file `foo.ext1` exists, ignore `foo.ext2`.

Where one thus provides `ext1` and `ext2`. In the case of the lexer/parser, this would mean applying this pattern for `.xx`/`.cpp` and `.yy`/`.cpp`.

This is probably not possible by `.gitignore` directly, but perhaps there are some hooks already implemented for this?

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way to do this. Is moving your `.yy` and corresponding `.cpp` files into a subdirectory, then ignoring all `.cpp` files in the directory an option?

Comment: @Chris: that's an option, but is of course more elegant if one can generate a generic way to ignore compiler-compiler products without having to worry about the file structure.

Comment: Are the files actually named according to some pattern like in the example above? You could ignore `lexer*.cpp` and `parser*.cpp`.

Comment: Or you could write a bash script updating .gitignore if you're using linux.

Answer (score 9):

I can see three ways to do this -- to answer the question directly, no, ignore processing consults only the pathname in question, not anything else about the environment.

1. Put your generated source in a `generated` folder you ignore.

   Me, I like this one best, I know I'm in a minority but I don't like build detritus in my source directories.
2. Have your makefile targets also update the `.gitignore`, with

   ```
   grep -qs ^target$ .gitignore || echo target >>.gitignore
   ```

   where `target` is the generated source file, as part of the recipe.
3. put some marker in the generated filenames themselves, `scanner.generated.c` or something.

For some reason I really dislike the pre-commit hook cleaning out unwanted source, git deleting things from a commit all by itself is just disturbing.

Comment: The OP suggested solution 1 would be inelegant but I think it is the most elegent. Folders should be structured around a system that seperates files according to logical groupings. E.g. many people separate .h and .cpp files because one is (for the most part) concerned with interface and one with implementation, giving the added benefit of being able to have a single point of reference for includes. Separating auto-generated source files avoids the OP's problem and means that a developer can work on an uncluttered folder containing only source files they will be editing.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is create a script to update .gitignore.
I don't know any, but you can look for a solution that runs this script automatically before a commit.

Edit: I Googled and found this: https://github.com/observing/pre-commit - 
Probably needs some tests.