# How to tell git to ignore a certain file if and only if another file exists?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to tell `git` to ignore a file named `foo.ext` if and only if there exists another file named `foo.txe`. I am almost sure that this cannot be done with the `.gitignore` syntax but there are maybe other tricky ways that I do not think of?

Example of use: I frequently store the figures of a LaTeX document in a sub-directory named `figures`. And I usually design my figures with Xfig. My makefile calls `fig2dev` to generate a pair of files from the `figures/foo.fig` source:

- `figures/foo.pdf`, a PDF file for the graphics part,
- `figures/foo.pdf_t`, a LaTeX file for the text, with an `includegraphics` command to include the PDF.

Because these two files are generated I'd like `git` to ignore them. I could add two simple exclude patterns to my `.gitignore` file but it also happens that some of my figures are in plain PDF, not generated from another source. And of course, I'd like `git` not to ignore these `figures/bar.pdf` files.

I'd like to add something like:

```
/\(**\)/figures/\(*\).fig: /\1/figures/\2.pdf /\1/figures/\2.pdf_t
```

to my `.gitignore` file, meaning that any file named `/<some_path>/figures/<some_name>.pdf` or `/<some_path>/figures/<some_name>.pdf_t` shall be ignored if and only if a file named `/<some_path>/figures/<some_name>.fig` exists with the same `<some_path>` and `<some_name>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitignore a file if file with different extension exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325195/gitignore-a-file-if-file-with-different-extension-exists)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use something in the file name or folder to determine what files are auto generated and which are not. Depending on how your code is setup you can ignore based on a folder. For example, use `figure-auto` for auto generated file and `figure` for manually created ones.

`figure-auto/`

If you only have a few files that you don't want to ignore you could use

```
figures/*.pdf
figures/*.pdf_t
!figures/keep-in-source-control.pdf
!figures/manually-created.pdf
```

[Git Ignore Pattern Format](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: I know how to use `.gitignore` and this is not what I was looking for, but thanks, I appreciate your help.